# action button extjs don't work

Tags: button, extjs4

i have a js view that contain button when i click this button i want to open another view 
and it connot work

this is my first view

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.login.WestMenu', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',    
alias: 'widget.westmenu',
frame:'true',

initComponent: function() {

    Ext.apply(this, {

        title: 'Writeup',
        animCollapse: true,
        width: 200,
        minWidth: 150,
        maxWidth: 400,
        iconCls:'logo',
        split: true,
        collapsible: true,

            items: [

                {

                    xtype : 'button',
                    text:'Ajouter réunion',
                    action:'meet',
                    iconCls:'add',
                    name:'meet',
                    width:120,
                    height:30,
                   x:20,
                   y:30

                }]

    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

and this is my second view

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.login.create-rd', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',    

alias: 'widget.test',
frame:'true', 

initComponent: function() {

 var win=  Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
     title: 'Ajouter réunion',
     width : 630,
     height: 600,
     layout: 'fit',
     iconCls:'add',

     items: [{
         xtype: 'form',

         id   : 'form-widgets',

         },

         items: [
             {
                 fieldLabel: 'date',
                 xtype     : 'datefield',
                 name      : 'date'
             }
         ],
     }

             ]
 }).show();   
 }
 });
```

and this is my controller

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.controller.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
refs: [{
    ref: 'Home',
    selector: 'home'
},
{
    ref: 'Login',
    selector: 'login'
}
],
stores: ['Login'],

models: ['Login'],

views: ['login.LoginForm','login.HomePage','login.CenterPanel','login.WestMenu','login.create-rd'],


init: function() {


    this.control({


        'login button[action=reset]': {  
            'click' : function(button, event, opt) {  

                var form = button.up('form');
                form.getForm().reset();
            }  
        },

        'login button[action=connect]': {  

            'click' :this.connect
        },
        'login button[action=meet]': {  

            'click' :this.meet
        }
    });
},
connect:function() 
{
this.getLogin().close();
var view1 = Ext.widget('home');


},
 meet:function() 
 {
 this.getHome().close();
 var view2 = Ext.widget('test');


}
});
```

please any one have a solution of this

Comment: Amin, please accept useful answers. Click the checkbox icon next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing that matches `login`. The selector `login button[action=reset]` means "Find a button xtype, with an attribute action, with a value reset, that exists as a child item under a container with xtype login".

It's the last past of your selector that's not satisfied.

Change the selector to:

`westmenu button[action=reset]`

Comment: thanx friend i do a copy paste ans i miss to change the name of widget

now it work correctly thanx